# An object instance not getting created in my test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise

The following is my test and everything works. The form gets filled with a name and image in the `ui` when I run the test. If I also test the presence of the user's name being created in the `ui` when I visit `groups_path` the test also passes. The only issue is that a `group` is not getting created. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm using `devise` for authentication

`create_group_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Creating a group', type: :feature do
  before :each do
    user = User.create!(name: 'Test user', email: 'test@gmail.com', password: '123456',
                       password_confirmation: '123456')
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end
  scenario 'adds a new group when name and image is entered' do
    visit new_group_path
    fill_in('Name', with: 'Sports')
    attach_file('Icon', "#{Rails.root}/integration_test_image/test.jpg")
    sleep(3)
    click_on 'Create Group'
    visit groups_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Sports')
  end
end
```

`groups_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to groups_url, notice: 'Group was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @group }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

 private
  
  def group_params
    params.require(:group).permit(:name, :icon)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No more sleeping on the job. `sleep x` doesn't actually guarentee that whatever your waiting for is actually finished - it just makes your tests slower and potentially flappy.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Creating a group', type: :feature do
  before :each do
    # You should be using fixtures or factories instead.
    user = User.create!(name: 'Test user', email: 'test@gmail.com', password: '123456',
                       password_confirmation: '123456')
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end
  scenario 'adds a new group when name and image is entered' do
    visit new_group_path
    fill_in('Name', with: 'Sports')
    # use a block instead of sleep
    # images should also go in /spec/support or /spec/fixtures
    attach_file('Icon', Rails.root.join("/integration_test_image/test.jpg")) do
      click_on 'Create Group' # no need to visit since it will redirect
      expect(page).to have_content('Sports') # have_content waits for the page to load
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `sleep(1)` after the `click_on 'Create Group'` line. I think by visiting the `groups_path` it happens too fast even before the `group object` creation is complete hence it becomes unavailable in the `ui` and is the reason for the test failing. Delaying the switch to the page by `1s` ensures the object completes being created and is available when the page is rendered hence the test passing.

Comment: You should not need this because you don't need to navigate. When you create a "Group" and it is successful it will redirect to `groups_url`. This means you do not need to `visit groups_path` because this is where you will already end up. In other words just `click_on('Create Group'); expect(page).to have_content('Sports')` should work fine

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, works and it's a better solution. I'm curious, originally after scaffolding, it redirects to `group_url(@group)`. In that scenario when I `visit_groups_path` in the test it fails without the `sleep(1)`. Would you say it's okay to use the `sleep method` in this scenario?